# Will I be able to make progress bar repeat every time in vb6?

Tags: vb6, progress-bar

Can I make a progress bar repeat it's loading process every time I load that page?
This is my code,

```
Private Sub Form_load()
Timer1.Interval = 50
Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
On Error Resume Next
PBcolor ProgressBar1, vbBlue, vbGreen
ProgressBar1 = ProgressBar1 + 1
If ProgressBar1.Value = 50 Then
ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1 + 50
If ProgressBar1.Value >= ProgressBar1.Max Then
Form7.Hide
form8.Show
End If
End If
ProgressBar1.Refresh
End Sub
```

When I run this code, the progress bar runs at first, but if I navigate to another form and come back (Without ending the program of course), it didn't run again. So could anyone suggest a solution please. Thank you.

Comment: You need to reset the progress bar to it's Min value.The refresh doesn't do that.

Comment: I tried to reset the progress bar to '0'. But after that it doesn't load at all. The form do not contain any code other than the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code depends on the progressbar value being less than the max value to do anything. The easiest thing you can do is just reset the value to the minimum when the form gets focus again. The **Form_Activate** event works well for this. Below I've formatted your original example and added the new event after your code.

```
Private Sub Form_load()

    Timer1.Interval = 50
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    On Error Resume Next

    PBcolor ProgressBar1, vbBlue, vbGreen
    ProgressBar1 = ProgressBar1 + 1
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 50 Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1 + 50
        If ProgressBar1.Value >= ProgressBar1.Max Then
            Form7.Hide
            form8.Show
        End If
    End If
    ProgressBar1.Refresh
End Sub

'Add this to the form with the progressbar
Private Sub Form_Activate()

    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Min

End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.! It solved my problem. Thank you jac for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

In my VB6 apps I use UserForm_Initialize or UserForm_Initialize (Depending on versions).

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ProgressBar1 = 0
    'Start Progress Bar

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Form_Activate() or the Form_GotFocus() event to reset your progressbar and restart loading